# How would I simplify this code to find the lowest inputed number?

Tags: java

```
while (choice != 6) {
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Rainfall Analysis Menu");
    System.out.println("1. Display total rainfall.");
    System.out.println("2. Display average daily rainfall.");
    System.out.println("3. Display day and amount of greatest rainfall.");
    System.out.println("4. Display day and amount of least rainfall.");
    System.out.println("5. Display number of days a flood alert was issued.");
    System.out.println("6. Quit");
    System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
    choice = keyboard.nextDouble();    

else if (choice == 4) {

if (rain1 < rain2 && rain1 < rain3 && rain1 < rain4 && rain1 < rain5 && rain1 < rain6 && rain1 < rain7 && rain1 < rain8 && rain1 < rain9 && rain1 < rain10) {
            System.out.print("Day 1 had the lowest rainfall with " + rain1 + "inches.");
    } else if (rain2 < rain1 && rain2 < rain3 && rain2 < rain4 && rain2 < rain5 && rain2 < rain6 && rain2 < rain7 && rain2 < rain8 && rain2 < rain8 && rain2 < rain9 && rain2 < rain10) {
            System.out.print("Day 2 had the lowest rainfall with " + rain2 + " inches.");
    } else if (rain3 < rain1 && rain3 < rain2 && rain3 < rain4 && rain3 < rain5 && rain3 < rain6 && rain3 < rain7 && rain3 < rain8 && rain3 < rain9 && rain3 < rain10) {
            System.out.print("Day 3 had the lowest rainfall with " + rain3 + " inches.");
    } else if (rain4 < rain1 && rain4 < rain2 && rain4 <rain3 && rain4 < rain5 && rain4 < rain6 && rain4 < rain7 && rain4 < rain8 && rain4 < rain8 && rain4 < rain9 && rain4 < rain10) {
            System.out.print("Day 4 had the lowest rainfall with " + rain4 + " inches.");
    } else if (rain5 < rain1 && rain5 < rain2 && rain5 < rain3 && rain5 < rain4 && rain5 < rain6 && rain5 < rain7 && rain5 < rain8 && rain5 < rain9 && rain5 < rain10) {
            System.out.print("Day 5 had the lowest rainfall with " + rain5 + " inches.");
    } else if (rain6 < rain1 && rain6 < rain2 && rain6 < rain3 && rain6 < rain4 && rain6 < rain5 && rain6 < rain7 && rain6 < rain8 && rain6 < rain9 && rain6 < rain10) {
            System.out.print("Day 6 had the lowest rainfall with " + rain6 + " inches.");
    } else if (rain7 < rain1 && rain7 < rain2 && rain7 < rain3 && rain7 < rain4 && rain7 < rain5 && rain7 < rain6 && rain7 < rain8 && rain7 < rain9 && rain7 < rain10) {
            System.out.print("Day 7 had the lowest rainfall with " + rain7 + " inches.");
    } else if (rain8 < rain1 && rain8 < rain2 && rain8 < rain3 && rain8 < rain4 && rain8 < rain5 && rain8 < rain6 && rain8 < rain7 && rain8 < rain9 && rain8 < rain10) {
            System.out.print("Day 8 had the lowest rainfall with " + rain8 + " inches.");
    } else if (rain9 < rain1 && rain9 < rain2 && rain9 < rain3 && rain9 < rain4 && rain9 < rain5 && rain9 < rain6 && rain9 < rain7 && rain9 < rain8 && rain9 < rain10) {
            System.out.print("Day 9 had the lowest rainfall with " + rain9 + " inches.");
    } else if (rain10 < rain1 && rain10 < rain2 && rain10 < rain3 && rain10 < rain4 && rain10 < rain5 && rain10 < rain6 && rain10 < rain7 && rain10 < rain8 && rain10 < rain9) {
            System.out.print("Day 10 had the lowest rainfall with " + rain10 + " inches.");
    }
```

I have a program that prompts the user to enter the amount of days they want to analyze, then enter the rainfall amount for those days (1-10 days). If the user wants to find the lowest amount of rainfall they input number 4 into the program which is supposed to print " Day x had the lowest rainfall with x inches. I came up with this solution above but want a way to simplify it to make it simple and shorter.

Comment: Use arrays instead of duplicate variables.

Comment: Day x had the lowest rainfall with y inches! :) Is it correct, to only mention 1 day, if more than one had the lowest amount of rainfall?

Comment: Use treeMap or other data structure class that store the min object every time you input the data.

Answer (score 0):

Store all of your variables in an array :

```
int[] rain = new int[]{1, 2, 15, 4,6 ...}
// note that 1,2,15 (ecc..) are example values to use instead of rain1, rain2 ...
```

then find the min value in the array and its index :

```
int min = Arrays.stream(rain).min().getAsInt(); 
int index = Arrays.asList(rain).indexOf(min);
// you can also write yourself some simple functions to get the those values
```

and then print it :

```
System.out.println("Day " + index + "had the lowest rainfall with " + min + " inches.");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about sorting a TreeMap, which keeps itself sorted:

```
TreeMap rainfall = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(); // First integer is rainfall amount and second integer is day number
rainfall.put(2, 1);
rainfall.put(8, 2);
rainfall.put(4, 3);
//etc
System.out.println("Day " + rainfall.get(1) + "had the lowest rainfall with " + rainfall.firstKey() + " inches.");
```

Comment: Actually, replace `rainfall.get(1)` with `rainfall.get(rainfall.firstKey())`

Answer (score 0):

Use a data structure to hold your data, so you don't have to manually hard code all possibilities. You can compress your codes by using a wrapper class to hold the information for day and rainfall:

```
public class RainfallData{

    private int day;
    private int rainfall;

    public RainfallData(int day, int rainfall){
        this.day = day;
        this.rainfall = rainfall;
    }
    //getters not shown
}
```

Then use a data structure such as arraylist to hold the rainfall records:

```
ArrayList<RainfallData> records = new ArrayList<>();
RainfallData minData = records.get(0);
for(RainfallData r : records)
    if(r.getRainfall() < minData)
        minData = r;
System.out.print("Day " + minData.getDay() + " had the lowest rainfall with " + minData.getRainfall() + " inches.");
```

With a dynamic set up like this, changes in number of days  or changes in number of attributes will have minimal effects on current code.